# Is there any way to convert a a large Excel CSV file to Google Sheet in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

In my Google App Maker application, I am trying to convert a large, user-uploaded Excel CSV file to Google Sheet. I have previously used these lines of code to convert smaller-size, user-uploaded Excel CSV files to Google Sheets:

```
     var xlsxBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(xlsxFileID).getBlob();
     var file = {
     };
     file = Drive.Files.update(file, ssFileID, xlsxBlob, {
       convert: true
     });
```

When I try uploading a large Excel CSV file, I get this error:

```
     Exception: File NAME.csv exceeds the maximum file size
```

My Excel CSV file is 56.5 MB. Is there any way to convert a large Excel CSV file to Google Sheet? I tried following this website: https://www.geek.com/apps/geek-101-how-to-open-a-csv-document-with-google-docs-1551489/ which converts a CSV file to Google Sheet immediately upon upload. However, I get an error: Upload failed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. Is there the CSV file in your Google Drive? 2. How many cells will you use for the CSV data? If the number is more than 2 million, you cannot convert it. At that time, it is required to separate CDV data, as Dimu Designs says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to break your csv into smaller chunks. Also, if the number of fields in the csv file is in excess of 2 million cells then you have another problem on your hands since a google sheet's max cell count is 2 million.

Google Sheets are not designed to handle large databases so you may have to look into using an alternative solution; if you plan on keeping your dev stack under Google's Cloud platform you can try Big Query, Cloud SQL, Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore.

Comment: does Google Sheets now have an updated max cell count of 4 million? @Dimu Designs

Comment: @Eric Not to my knowledge. The last time the limit was raised was back in Dec 2013, where the cell count went from 400,000 to 2,000,000. I'm not aware of any increases in cell count since then.